# Spring Security - AngularJS - Protect Angular static content

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

long story short, I am trying to protect some legacy Angular application with Spring Security. 
Whole Angular static stuff is under

```
src/main/resources/static
```

and all stuff which should be subject to securing is under

```
src/main/resources/static/protected-stuff
```

Here is my configuration (it is part of overall Spring Boot app configuration):

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/dologin")
                .failureForwardUrl("/login.html?isError=true")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?isError=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/protected-stuff/index.html")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/index.html", "/home.html", "/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/protected-stuff/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Now, the part which is problematic to me is:

```
                    .antMatchers("/protected-stuff/**").authenticated()
```

Redirecting on errorneus login, processing login request (it hits AuthenticationProvider) etc works but **redirection to protected stuff after successful authentication results in redirection back to login page**. Now I suspect resource filters and Spring Sec interceptors (ok, again, filters) are clashing with each other but I can't be really sure is it possible to overcome such situation?

Any help/suggestion is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to determine what is actual issue by debugging through Spring Security and through Spring Boot. Actually it was ordering of configurations which Spring Boot loads. Nothing in Spring Security itself. So basically it was just about giving Spring Sec's config highest order.